# Unable to send data using $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

testfrm1.php

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post"> 
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr class="block_sortlines">
                    <th class="req" width="15%">Problem</th>
                    <th class="req" width="15%">Location</th>
                    <th width="12%">Priority</th>
                    <th style="width:10%;"class="action"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="maintenance_row_1">
                    <td> New Problem </td>
                    <td> balcony </td>
                    <td> high </td>
                    <td> <a class="action button right js-edit-subtask-1" onClick="editSubtask(1);">Edit Sub</a> </td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_location_id]" value="12345" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_problem_id]" value="13456" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_priority_id]" value="56436" />
                </tr>
                <tr id="maintenance_row_2">
                    <td> New Problem1 </td>
                    <td> balcony1 </td>
                    <td> low </td>
                    <td> <a href="" class="action button right js-edit-subtask-2">Edit Sub</a> </td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[2][maintenance_location_id]" value="1111" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[2][maintenance_problem_id]" value="2223" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[2][maintenance_priority_id]" value="23523" />
                </tr>
                <tr id="maintenance_row_3">
                    <td> prob1 </td>
                    <td> bathroom </td>
                    <td> test </td>
                    <td> <a class="action button right">Edit Sub</a> </td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[3][maintenance_location_id]" value="54321" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[3][maintenance_problem_id]" value="65432" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="sub_maintenance_template[3][maintenance_priority_id]" value="76896" />
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <h4 class="left">Sub-tasks</h4>
                <a href="" class="action button right js-add-subtask"><i class="add"></i> Sub-task</a>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>

        <script>
        function editSubtask( intSubTaskId ){
            alert( intSubTaskId);
            subMaintenanceTemplateRow = $('#maintenance_row_'+intSubTaskId);

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "testFrm2.php",
              data: {"pTableData" : subMaintenanceTemplateRow.serialize()}
            });
        }

    </script>
    </body>
```

testFrm2.php

```
<?php
$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);
$tableData = json_decode($tableData,TRUE);
print_r( $tableData);
?>
```

testFrm1.php is basic form. On clicking of edit button calling testFrm2.php.
I am trying to print contents on testFrm2.php but it prints nothing. Any help in this? Might be there is some wrong with $.ajax method. Passing data of table row to $.ajax method.

Comment: table row data is not getting serialized . like tr id => maintenance_row_1

Comment: why you want it inside `pTableData` ? why not submit the serialized form data directly

Comment: What data exactly do you want to send? Entire `tr`?

Comment: @GytisTenovimas : yes I want to send entire tr data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `serialize()` method on the wrong selector, also the way you are handling submitted data in PHP is also incorrect. There are two ways in which you can solve this:

**Method(1):**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {"pTableData" : JSON.stringify(subMaintenanceTemplateRow.children('input').serializeArray())},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Use `serializeArray()` method to encode the *input* elements as an array of name and values, and then use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the array to a JSON string. This way you don't have to change anything in PHP code.

```
<?php
    $tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);
    $tableData = json_decode($tableData,TRUE);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($tableData);
?>
```

**Method(2):**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {"pTableData" : subMaintenanceTemplateRow.children('input').serializeArray()},
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
});
```

Use `serializeArray()` method to encode the *input* elements as an array of name and values and directly send it to your *testFrm2.php* page. This way you don't have to decode anything, you can simply access the array like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST['pTableData']);
?>
```

#### Update(1):

As per [**your requirement below**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710862/unable-to-send-data-using-ajax/49711297#comment86488819_49711297), *Can i get array like this - `[sub_maintenance_template] => Array ( [3] => ( [maintenance_location_id]=> 54321 [maintenance_problem_id]=> 65432 [maintenance_priority_id]=>76896 [description]=> sample description ) )`*, change the backend PHP code on *testFrm2.php* page in the following way,

```
<?php
    $resultArr = array(
        'sub_maintenance_template' => array(
            'maintenance_location_id' => $_POST['pTableData'][0]['value'],
            'maintenance_problem_id' => $_POST['pTableData'][1]['value'],
            'maintenance_priority_id' => $_POST['pTableData'][2]['value'],
            'description' => 'your sample descrition'
        )
    );
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($resultArr);
?>
```

Comment: Got following array : Array ( [0] => Array(
            [name] => sub_maintenance_template[3][maintenance_location_id]
            [value] => 54321
        )

    [1] => Array(
            [name] => sub_maintenance_template[3][maintenance_problem_id]
            [value] => 65432
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => sub_maintenance_template[3][maintenance_priority_id]
            [value] => 76896
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => sub_maintenance_template[3][description]
            [value] => sample description
        )

)

Comment: Can i get array like this -
    `[sub_maintenance_template] => Array (
 [3] =>
        (
            [maintenance_location_id]=> 54321
   [maintenance_problem_id]=> 65432
   [maintenance_priority_id]=>76896
   [description]=> sample description
        )
)`

Comment: @PranavUnde I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer.